# d3: make the d3.csv function syncronous

Tags: d3.js

Is there any way to make d3.csv() be synchronous instead of asynchronous?

My code is getting to be a mess with callbacks since I load multiple csv files according to different triggers on the page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

d3.csv is asynchronous by design to prevent pages from freezing up, so that can't be changed without changing the d3 library itself.

However, you could pre-load all your files via d3.text() and call d3.csv.parse or d3.csv.parseRows, which will be synchronous given that the text file has been loaded.

For an example, see Mike Bostock's answer in this post [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870265/read-csv-tsv-with-no-header-line-in-d3).

Comment: All of the functions you've mentioned are asynchronous. They are making AJAX requests, so there's nothing you can do to make them synchronous. If you want synchronous data loading, you have to embed the data in the page.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not possible with d3 (as mentioned by THK), it is possible with jquery.ajax(), where there is an async field that can be set to false. See the example below:

```
function getdatafromfile(filename)  {
// Read annotation file. Example : %timeinstant \t %value \n
// Return an array of string
var arraydata;
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: filename,
      dataType: "text",
      async: false,
      success: function(csv) {arraydata = $.csv.toArrays(csv,{separator:'\t'}); }
      });
return arraydata;
}
```

Comment: Semicolons are not required on the `var` and the `return` ?  Is this standard js allows that?

Comment: and btw this seems to be a v nice solution.  Is there something similar for more general processing (i.e. not necessarily url fetching?)

Comment: @javadba. I edited the answer and added semicolons. Thanks for the comments

Comment: the `$.csv` is not resolving: browser says `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve 'call back hell' by combining d3.js with deferred/promise.

Example with Jquery.deferred:

```
var getCsv = function (csvUrl) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    d3.csv(csvUrl, function (error, rows) {
        if (error) {
            defer.reject(error);
        }
        defer.resolve(rows);
    });
    return defer.promise();
};

$.when(
    getCsv("data/test1.csv"), // please pass csv url as you like
    getCsv("data/test2.csv")  // please pass csv url as you like
).done(function (res1, res2) {
    console.log(res1); // test1.csv parsed by d3.js
    console.log(res2); // test2.csv parsed by d3.js
}).fail(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```