# Why is my D3.csv() method is getting back "undefined"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I just have a csv file and I'm trying to get the data with an async function but I'm getting undefined.

```
<script>
    async function data(pathToCsv) {
        return await d3.csv(pathToCsv, function (data) {
            data.year = +data.year
            data.running_total = +data.running_total
            data.date = new Date(data.year, 0)
            return data
        })
    };
    let dataset = data('q3.csv');
    console.log(dataset.year);
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899005/d3-make-the-d3-csv-function-syncronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that your data function is returning a promise, and so accessing `year` from a promise object will return `undefined`, you need to add `await` when calling your `data function`

```
 async function data(pathToCsv) {
        return await d3.csv(pathToCsv, function (data) {
            data.year = +data.year
            data.running_total = +data.running_total
            data.date = new Date(data.year, 0)
            return data
        })
   };

  async function init() {
     let dataset = await data('q3.csv');
     // this should work now assuming you are using d3 function correctly as i'm not aware of d3 functions myself
     console.log(dataset.year); 
  }

  init()
```

Comment: Getting undefined still

Comment: @RaminMelikov then either csv does return a promise that resolves to undefined, or the data you are accessing is not correct, anyway after a quick search it seems for me the csv function does return an array, and so u might wanna try dataset[0].year. Either case sart with console.log(dataset) and see what happens. I can help you more if u setup a reproducible example using codesandbox or something similar

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```
<script>

    async function data(pathToCsv) {
        let dataset = await d3.csv(pathToCsv, function (d) {
            d.year = +d.year
            d.running_total = +d.running_total
            d.date = new Date(d.year, 0)
            return d
        })
        return dataset
    };

    data('q3.csv').then(function(d) {
        d.forEach(function(p){
            console.log(p.date.getFullYear());
        })
    });

</script>
```