# Is there a way to make the data loaded from the d3.csv function global?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, dataset

Ok, big disclaimer: I'm a novice programmer, and this is my first time ever with javascript and d3.js.

I'm working on a project using d3.js. I have 100 datasets(all stored locally in a folder) of different cryptocurrencies, and I'd like to build graphs to study them.
I've implemented nice functions to draw interactive graphs and to preprocess data. **Everything works just fine as long as I decide to work with a single dataset.
Why? Because I'm basically doing all the things that I'd like to do with my data inside the callback of the d3.csv(path,callback(data){...}).**

**Since I'd like to change *dynamically* the datasets(a.k.a. the path)**, for example with a dropdown menu, I'd like to have a way to load the csv like I'd do in python:

```
with open('testfile.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
```

**I thought that a possible solution would have been to create a global variable and filling it with the preprocessed data** inside the callback... but if I try to print or to use in any way these data inside the global variable, **this is not working**(I readed every stackoverflow post about this and I'm 99.9% saying that it's an asynchronicity issue)(check snippet of code down here).

```
// SNIPPET OF CODE THAT IT DOES **NOT** WORK

var my_global_variable = {"name": keyword,"date": [], "high": [],"low": [],"market cap": [],"open": [],"close": [],"volume": []};

 var _data_ = d3.csv(path, function(data) {
      my_global_variable = FunctionToProcessData(data)
    })
console.log(my_global_variable)
```

The print I get is the following(sorry,not enough reputation on SO for posting an image):

```
{name: "Dogecoin", date: Array(0), high: Array(0), low: Array(0), market cap: Array(0), …}
```

**But it's weird because if I click the dropdown arrow** on the console of my browser where I'm running the code, even though here it is written that each array inside the keys of my_global_variable is empty( 0), after clicking it **I WILL SEE ELEMENTS**, like if they get created only when I specifically requested it:

```
{name: "Dogecoin", date: Array(0), high: Array(0), low: Array(0), market cap: Array(0), …}
  close: (1378) ["0.000772", "0.000755", "0.000862",  …]
  date: (1378) [Fri Sep 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale), …]
  market cap: (1378) ["84749600", "94429700", "97923500", …]
  name: "Dogecoin"
  open: (1378) ["0.000762", "0.00085", "0.000881", …]
  volume: (1378) ["3758470", "3157030", "4641920",  …]
  __proto__: Object
```

I'm not an expert of javascript: is there a way to load data from a local folder and use them as I would do simply in python? A.K.A. : Can anyone give me a solution for this?

I report here my code to clear any possible doubt:
HTML FILE:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <script src="test.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="my_dataviz">
        </div>        
    </body>
```

Javascript test.js file:

```
var keyword = "Dogecoin";
var path = `archive/${keyword}.csv`;

var data_final = {"key": keyword,"values": []}

var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz").append("svg").attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g").attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")").attr("id", 1)
    
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},

width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var _data_ = d3.csv(path, function(data) {
  data_final = FunctionToProcessData(data)
  draw_time_chart(svg,margin,data_final,attr) 
})




function FunctionToProcessData(data){
 // do stuff with my data. 
 // It's quite long and not the point of this question,
 // so I won't copypaste it here
 
 return data_final
}

function draw_time_chart(svg,margin,data_final,attr){
     // do stuff to draw a graph with my data. 
     // It's quite long and not the point of this question,
     // so I won't copypaste it here
}
```

P.S. Yes,I have already checked [d3: make the d3.csv function syncronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899005/d3-make-the-d3-csv-function-syncronous) , but this didn't solve my issue.

Comment: There are a lot of issues involved in answering this question making it borderline "too broad". You cannot store the data globally as you laid out in your post because of the asynchronous nature of the loading: See [*"How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?"*](/q/14220321). The console is different because it is defined async by default and awaits the results of your calls. A good starting point for your task might be [*"Load multiple files using the d3-fetch module"*](/q/49239474).