# why Graph is not showing until i minimize window. (using chart.js )

Tags: javascript, html, graph, chart.js, render

I'm using chart.js for first time and I'm facing problem in drawing graph. When I run this code, Graph axis are shown only but bars are not shown until I minimize or change browser window size. This is happening every time. Maybe this has to do with responsiveness. Any help about what I'm doing wrong here. I'm using visual studio and chrome for rendering graph.

```js
let labels=[]
let duration=[]

let file="assets/duration.csv";
d3.csv(file).then(
    function (loaddata) {
                
        for (let i = 0; i < loaddata.length; i++) {
            //console.log(loaddata.hours)
            if (loaddata[i].hours != 0)
            {
                duration.push(loaddata[i].hours)
                labels.push(loaddata[i].Trend)
            }
            
        }
        //console.log(labels)
        //console.log(duration)
}
);
let options={
    type: 'bar',
    responsive: true,
    title: {
        display:true,
        text:'Duration of Trending Tweets'
    },
    data: {
        labels:labels,
        datasets:[{
            data: duration,
            label: 'Hours',
            backgroundColor:["#3e95cd"]
            
        }]
    }
};

let chart=new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas'),options);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.1/dist/chart.min.js">

    </script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My first website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:80vw">

        </canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js">    
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create the chart before the `CSV` data is loaded. Be aware that the `d3.csv` request is processed asynchronously.

This can be solved by creating the chart only once the `CSV` data is fully loaded (at the end and inside of `d3.csv(file).then( ...` ).

An alternative approach is described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19899811/2358409).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got your point and resolved my issue

Comment: Glad I could help: Please mark the answer as accepted if you think it was the solution to your problem (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/2358409).