# how to read a text file by lines with d3.js (like readlines in python)

Tags: d3.js, text

I want to plot a picture with D3.
The data is from text file
like this:
a.txt:

```
1 200
2 300
3 220
```

I try to read the file in this way

```
    d3.text("850191387_full_info.txt",function(error,data)
{
  if(error)
    return console.error(error);
  d3.select("body")
    .append("p")
    .text(data);
});
```

But it can only appear the whole data in web page.
How can I plot a simple line chart with this txt file?
the first column as x variable, and the second column as y variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870265/read-csv-tsv-with-no-header-line-in-d3

Comment: It means I should transform the txt into csv at first?

Comment: yes, its better that way