# Using d3.js (v5) to read a csv that has no header

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

What is the best way in 2018 to read in a CSV file that has no header row using d3.js?

**CSV**

```
"d1","d2","d3"
"dx","dy","dz"
"d4","d5","d6"
```

This is what I’ve got from another [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870265/read-csv-tsv-with-no-header-line-in-d3):

```
d3.text("data.csv", function(text) {
  const data = d3.csv.parseRows(text, function(d) {
    return d.map(String);
  });
  console.log(data);
});
```

Yet, I get no console output. What’s the mistake?

Comment: All d3 functions that used XHR (d3.text, d3.csv, d3.tsv, d3.json...) moved to promises now.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I wouldn't consider this a duplicate; there is more to it than just the switch to the Fetch API.

Comment: Thanks for the Link you provided @GerardoFurtado; it works for reading it in as plain text:

`d3.text("data.csv").then(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});`

Yet its not when I try to combine with another then to parse the Rows...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using D3 v5, the pattern described in that answer (which is 6 years old) doesn't work anymore: unlike previous versions, which used XMLHttpRequest, the new version uses promises.

That alone qualifies your question as a duplicate. However, I'm writing this answer because there is an important piece of code missing in your question: the piece that adds the **header row**.

So, since this is v5, this is the pattern you have to use:

```
d3.text("data.csv").then(function(data){
    //....
})
```

Inside the callback, you have to add the first row:

```
data = "foo,bar,baz\n" + data;
```

Then, you can parse it, using `d3.csvParse`:

```
var newData = d3.csvParse(data);
```

Because we can't use `d3.text` in the S.O. snippet, here is a bl.ocks with the demo: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/8849016b91b41ae463408c747417af95/8b299a22639621ae7619628a5b10fb9257783b8d

Comment: BTW, I also [commented](https://gist.github.com/GerardoFurtado/8849016b91b41ae463408c747417af95#gistcomment-2626088) on your gist: "Why would you add a header row to it? To stick to the question's original code you could just use d3.csvParseRows(), right?" This, obviously, does also apply to your now undeleted answer.

Comment: @altocumulus now I'm totally lost: why did you say that *"there is more to it"*?

Comment: What I meant was: Not only the Fetch API but also the parsing: `d3.csv.parseRows` → `d3.csvParseRows`. Your answer started off in the right direction covering both issues but got somewhat lost when needlessly introducing a header row which OP did not ask for.