# D3 / JavaScript load data and return value

Tags: javascript, function, csv, d3.js, return

I do not seem to understand why I cannot return the following values. I want to use custom colors for coloring a bar chart.

```
function farbe() {
  d3.csv("./Barchart_Farben.csv", function(data) {

    farbdat = new Array;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        farbdat.push(data[i].Farbe);
    }
      console.log(farbdat);
      return(farbdat);      
  });
  };

console.log(farbe());
```

Output:

> undefined
>
> Array(5) [ "yellow", "violet", "orange", "red", "lightyellow" ]

Nothing gets returned. Why?

```
// ./Barchart.csv: 
// Farbe 
// yellow
// violet
// orange
// red
// lightyellow
```

Comment: As I like to say, there are two types of programmers: *...and those who don't. Those who understand asynchronous code...*

Comment: Thanks, now I kind of understood what's going on!

Comment: That's good. And please don't get offended by my joke, I never meant to be rude. I love that joke! I read it somewhere, I don't remember where, but it captures nicely the nature of an asynchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `d3.csv` function doesn't return anything. Try this.

```js
function farbe() {
  var returnData = [];
  d3.csv("./Barchart_Farben.csv", function(data) {

    farbdat = new Array;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      farbdat.push(data[i].Farbe);
    }
    console.log(farbdat);
    returnData = farbdat;
  });
 return returnData;
};
```

you must check `typeof` and `undefined` for input parameter 'data' before looping on it.

Comment: Please give me the reason for downvote. will help me to improve my skills :)

Comment: Thanks, but did not work. Typeof data ist object.

Comment: @Krisselack: now check it again. I have added the return in the function.

Comment: That returned an empty Array.

Comment: Just FYI: `d3.csv` always returns something, in any version (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47664293/5768908)). On top of that your solution won't work, because `d3.csv` is asynchronous.

Comment: @Krisselack Use this link -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870265/read-csv-tsv-with-no-header-line-in-d3

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll try this out next time. Meanwhile I solved the issue by including the color column to my bargraph data set and I was able to access it in the main d3-function.

Answer (score -1):

`return` is not a function, is a statement. You should write `return farbdat` instead of `return(farbdat)`.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please add a reason.

Comment: Thanks, but did not work.

Comment: Agreed, [`return`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#prod-ReturnStatement) is a statement. But that statement returns the value of an expression following the `return` keyword. `(farbdat)`, on the other hand, is a perfectly fine expression which is basically the same as `farbdat` itself. Sure, it may look weird and it may be an indication that an inexperienced coder is off the track but the code is valid. The problem is  a completely different one, namely asynchronous execution.

Comment: @altocumulus Cool, thanks for the explanation! I did not see that.